# Convert dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss to new date() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert `22-06-2021 10:14:17` to `new Date()`, but it is being marked as an invalid date.

Here is the code:

```js
var dateString = "22-06-2021 10:14:17"; // Oct 23
 
var dateObject = new Date(dateString);

document.body.innerHTML = dateObject.toString();
```

Comment: how is the `"22-06-2021 10:14:17"` string generated, can it be converted to an iso date string?

Comment: Why would `22-06` be `Oct 23` and not June 22?

Comment: in javascript  `mm-dd-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` format are considered by default. try getting this format or use helper library like **moment** or **dateformat**

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat the **moment** is deprecated. It is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setDateTime(dateTime) {
  const [date, time] = dateTime.split(" ");
  const [DD, MM, YYYY] = date.split("-");
  const [h, m, s] = time.split(":");
  return new Date(YYYY, MM - 1, DD, h, m, s);
}

const dateObject = setDateTime("22-06-2021 10:14:17")

console.log(dateObject);
document.body.innerHTML = dateObject.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) can accept a numeric value (milliseconds from 1970), a string in ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mssZ`) or the separate numeric values in descending order

Examples:

```js
console.log(new Date()); // today
console.log(new Date(1624346057000)); // ms from 1970
console.log(new Date("2021-06-22T07:14:17.000Z"));
console.log(new Date(2021, 5, 22, 7, 14, 17));
```

Assuming you can accept string with this format `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss`, then you can use a regex to parse the string and pass the separate values to the constructor.

```js
var dateString = "22-06-2021 10:14:17"; // Oct 23

var [, date, month, year, hour, min, sec] = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/.exec(dateString).map(Number);

var dateObject = new Date(year, month - 1, date, hour, min, sec);

console.log(dateObject.toISOString()); // gmt
console.log(dateObject.toString()); // local
```

Keep in mind that the months are index-based so they start from 0 (0-11 instead of 1-12)